# Combine AdaBoost and Support Vector Regression?

Tags: svm, boosting, svr

I have read several papers about using SVM instead of decision tree in AdaBoost, but I haven't seen any papers about using support vector regression (SVR) in AdaBoost. However, if using support vector regression in AdaBoost, I have to weaken SVR. So how do I weaken SVR when combining it with AdaBoost?